# Is there any HTTP client with Socket.outputProgress support for uploading?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

URLLoader doesn't dispatch PROGRESS event when uploading data, but latest Socket implementation has support for outputProgress Event [1].

Is there any HTTP client which can track upload progress by using  outputProgress?

[1] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#event:outputProgress

Comment: [AS3HttpClient](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient) uses the `Socket` class to do HTTP, if it doesn't do what you want, it might be the best place to start. There is even an old plea from the developer for Adobe to support outputProgress in Socket.

Answer (score 1):

> AS3HttpClient uses the Socket class to do HTTP, if it doesn't do what you want, it might be the best place to start. There is even an old plea from the developer for Adobe to support outputProgress in Socket

**References**

- [AS3HTTPClient](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient)